# About Google's upcoming retirement of Billing 3.0

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, google-pay

Regarding the issue that Google is about to deactivate Billing 3.0, I want to know that I use the IAP billing function in Unity, but Google told me that they are about to deactivate this version, but their official does not support the upgrade of the Unity version, I Do I need to replace my code to use Androi integration instead of Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window -> Package Manager and update the In App Purchasing plugin. No, you don't need to update any of the existing code.

[image: IAP pack in Package Manager]

Comment: Thank you for your answer I updated Unity to 2020.3.40 to update my IAP version. But now I have new problems due to the upgrade haha